# sort on array read

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my controller I have

```
var $uses = array('User','Customer');
```

then I am using read to call the users

```
$loggedOutCustomer = $this->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'));
```

this gives me users and cutsomers that I can use but I want to do a sort on customers name. How can i do that in cake?

Comment: Please tag only the version you are using. And what is the relationship between User and Customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default order in your User model.

If Customer belongsTo User, User hasMany Customer.

In your User model, under the `hasMany` variable, find the Customer record and add `Customer.name` to the `order` array key.

Also, please remove the cakephp version tag that you are not using.

You can also add your sorting options when you're using the [find()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find) method of your model.

This can also be defined in the [pagination array](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1232/Controller-Setup)

Another option would be to use the [Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)

Comment: Is there a solution if he wants to order by a different key in another place in his code? I.e. there should be a way to pass an `order` parameter..

Comment: @oerd yup, he can define it in the `find()` call or on the pagination (`paginate`) array. He can also use the `Containable` behavior. Which is recommended

Comment: I think you should put these comments in the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
$loggedOutCustomer = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')), 'order' => 'Customer.name ASC'));
```